# Error Message When Run DSharp Example

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have installed all Dsharp Packages in Delphi XE. But when I run the example, I always get the following error message:

> Exception: Patching : ObjAuto.GetTypeSize failed. Do you have set a breakpoint in the method?

Has anybody found a workaround for this error?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The library is trying to apply a runtime code patch to fix a defect in the `ObjAuto.GetTypeSize` RTL function. The code that does this can be seen here: https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/dsharp/src/ad7c5983505f0117f1347f92d2bb96c07bdfda94/Source/Core/ObjAutoPatch.pas?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

The call to `FindMethodBytes` fails. Because this function is about to modify the executing code to install the runtime patch, it first checks that the code is as it expects it to be. It searches through the code looking for a known signature for that function.

That signature cannot be found and the patch therefore cannot be installed. Hence the error message. Some possible reasons for the patch code failing in this way:

1. A breakpoint is set in this code. Breakpoints are implemented by temporarily modifying the code to contain breakpoint instructions.
2. You are compiling and linking against your own modified version of the RTL. Because of this, the function signature is different.
3. Another unit in your program is also patching this same function, and the second attempt to patch fails for obvious reasons.
4. You are using debug DCUs that have a different signature from the standard DCUs.
5. There is a defect in the DSharp code. Perhaps an erroneous signature, that was not tested on your version of the Delphi RTL. That's not very likely. Perhaps you have installed a hotfix or Delphi update that has not been tested by Stefan. Or perhaps you have not installed a hotfix or update that you are expected to have installed. Maybe the linker has stripped so much code (or so little) that the signature search fails.

And the issue could be due to some other reason that I've not yet thought of. Fundamentally, though, these are all variants on the same theme. The code encountered at runtime is not as expected. I do recommend that you try to find out why so that you can determine how best to proceed.

Given that there are so many possible causes for this message, I've simply tried to explain the conceptual reason for it, but now it's really over to you to debug the specifics in your environment.

Comment: Thanks david, i have solved it by deleting the script that generate that exception

Comment: Even with debug DCUs this should not fail because afaik (when I tested this) they don't have any different compiler settings (only debug symbols on) that affect the generated code. I highly suspect not having installed update 1 for Delphi XE. It might also fail if you have added ObjAuto.pas directly to your project and compile that with the project settings that generates different bytecode.

Comment: @Stefan re debug DCUs that's what I thought too, but I was clutching at straws

Comment: @bagus Er, that doesn't sound like a great solution to me. I'd seek to understand.

Comment: @David : Yes I Agree with you. But, for the time being it's ok for me :). Tq